# How do I use all() built-in function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am attempting to use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) but it is not working for me:

```
>>> names = ["Rhonda", "Ryan", "Red Rackham", "Paul"]
>>> all([name for name in names if name[0] == "R"])
True
>>>
```

I am trying to check if all the names begin with `"R"`, and even though I added `"Paul"` to `names`, `all()` still returns `True`. How do I fix this so that `all()` returns `False` until `"Paul"` is removed?

Comment: What were you expecting ?

Comment: Aside: strings have a `startswith` method, so `name.startswith("R")` works too.

Comment: `if all(c[0] == "R" for c in names):`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misunderstand how `all` works.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

> `all(iterable)`
>
> Return `True` if all elements of the `iterable` are true (or if the
>   `iterable` is empty).

In your code, you are first collecting all names that start with `R` into a list and then passing this list to `all`.  Doing this will always return `True` because non-empty strings evaluate to `True`.

---

Instead, you should write:

```
all(name[0] == "R" for name in names)
```

This will pass an iterable of booleans to `all`.  If all of them are `True`, the function will return `True`; otherwise, it will return `False`.

As an added bonus, the result will now be computed lazily because we used a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) instead of a list comprehension.  With the list comprehension, the code needed to test *all* strings before determining a result.  The new code however will only check as many as necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to put an *evaluating* list comprehension in the `all` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ["Rhonda", "Ryan", "Red Rackham", "Paul"]
print all(map(lambda name: name[0] == "R", names))
# prints False
names = ["Rhonda", "Ryan", "Red Rackham"]
print all(map(lambda name: name[0] == "R", names))
# prints True
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you were getting wrong result was because you are already creating a new list using list comprehension by applying the desired condition, So if we do a little breakdown then:

```
>>> print [name for name in names if name[0] == "R"]
>>> ['Rhonda', 'Ryan', 'Red Rackham']
>>> print all(['Rhonda', 'Ryan', 'Red Rackham'])
>>> True
```

So the correct way may be:

```
names = ["Rhonda", "Ryan", "Red Rackham", "Paul"]

res = all(map(lambda x : x[0]=="R", names))
# map() returns: [True, True, True, False] 
# all([True, True, True, False]) == False
print res
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ["Rhonda", "Ryan", "Red Rackham", "Paul"]
if all(c[0] == "R" for c in names):
    print "ALL MATCH"
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/KenqJl